# "ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded && Exception in thread "ActiveMQ Transport Server: "

Tags: garbage-collection, out-of-memory, activemq-classic, consumer, overhead

Getting below exception in application startup log, after 5 to 1 week gap.

```
Exception in thread "ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQDestination.getQualifiedName(ActiveMQDestination.java:232)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.expireMessages(Queue.java:928)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.access$100(Queue.java:106)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue$2.run(Queue.java:149)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.SchedulerTimerTask.run(SchedulerTimerTask.java:33)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

Exception in thread "ActiveMQ Transport Server: ssl://<ip>:<port>?socket.needClientAuth=true" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.<init>(InputRecord.java:93)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.<init>(AppInputStream.java:50)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.init(SSLSocketImpl.java:640)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:524)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.accept(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:343)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportServer.doRunWithServerSocket(TcpTransportServer.java:403)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportServer.run(TcpTransportServer.java:325)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "pool-3-thread-123443" Exception in thread "ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler" Exception in thread "pool-3-thread-123443" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

and application got killed after writing the GC statement.

Can anyone please help me on these issue to get more understanding on solution perspective.

Note: Not changed the default system usage memory comes with activemq. This entire application is to consume messages from activemq queue ssl://:?socket.needClientAuth=true. should i need to modify the broker URL to add anything? please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

Comment: This is something related to activemq consumer running env side. not in eclipse. Something related to transport layer of activemq

Comment: that's irrelevant, the answers are not specific to eclipse and describe the meaning of that exception. These types of exception can occur on any random allocator callsite in your application if your application is misbehaving.

Comment: Yah, i have read all that page. and i got to know the definition what this error means.  But my question here is OOM happening in ActiveMQ Broker service side. so wanted to know if there is any help regarding this to tune activeMQ brokers so that GC will happen quickly. Please help